# Using mongodb java driver, can you sort by something other than distance when using $nearsphere?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using a $nearsphere query and then applying a sort by date to the cursor but mongo seems to ignore the sort by date. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Add some more context to you question. It would be easier to tell with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either sort the results in Java or you could use the aggregation framework.

To do a query with aggregation, you have to use the [Collection.aggregate](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#aggregate%28com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject...%29) method. This method requires two DBObjects as parameters:

1. your search query
2. your aggregation command which should look like that: `{ $sort: { date: 1 } }`

The return value of Collection.aggregate is an [AggregationOutput](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/AggregationOutput.html) object which implements Iterable and thus can be iterated in a for-loop.

Further information can be found here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-aggregation-framework-with-java-driver/

Comment: For this to work wouldn't the search query (1.) itself have to be an aggregation function? ie $match $sort $group.....